# For loop: process iterates well for about half of the items in the list, but stops short?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently scraping and storing in text files 911 speeches from http://www.millercenter.org/. The whole HTML processing piece of my code works; it's when I try to iterate (in the `for` loop at the end) over the URLs contained in the list `every_link` where I run into issues. The `processURL()` function stops working for about half of my links - so I don't get half of the speeches I need. The `for` loop iterates seemingly at random through `every_link`, because while speeches from Presidents George W. Bush and Harry Truman were scraped, speeches from guys like Grover Cleveland were not. What's the issue with my `for` loop?

```
import urllib2,sys,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
from string import punctuation as p
from multiprocessing import Pool
import re, nltk
import requests
reload(sys)

os.chdir('U:/Fall 2015/ENGL 3XX')
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

#==============================================================================
# Scraping and cleaning one speech from Obama to show the method works
#==============================================================================

obama_4427_url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427'
obama_4427 = urllib2.urlopen(obama_4427_url).read()
obama_4427 = BeautifulSoup(obama_4427)

# find the speech itself within the HTML
obama_4427 = obama_4427.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})

# obama_4427_div.text removes extraneous characters (e.g. '<br/>')
obama_4427 = obama_4427.text.lower()

# for further text analysis, remove punctuation
punctuation = re.compile('[{}]+'.format(re.escape(p)))

# obama_4427_nopunct = [line.decode('utf-8').strip() for line in obama_4427_html.readlines()]

obama_4427 = punctuation.sub('', obama_4427)
obama_4427 = obama_4427.replace('—',' ')
obama_4427 = obama_4427.replace('transcript','')

# divide obama_4427_str_processed into individual words
words = obama_4427.split(' ')

#==============================================================================
# Cleaning links begins below, so that  we can process all 911 speeches through processURL()
#==============================================================================

url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/speeches'
url2 = 'http://www.millercenter.org'

conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = conn.read()

miller_center_soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = miller_center_soup.find_all('a')

linklist = [tag.get('href') for tag in links if tag.get('href') is not None]

# remove all items in list that don't contain 'speeches'
linkslist = [_ for _ in linklist if re.search('speeches',_)]
del linkslist[0:2]

# concatenate 'http://www.millercenter.org' with end of speech links
every_link_dups = [url2 + end_link for end_link in linkslist]

# remove duplicates
seen = set()
every_link = [] # no duplicates array
for l in every_link_dups:
    if l not in seen:
        every_link.append(l)
        seen.add(l)

# list of presidents (print(len(set(presidents))) = 43 total)
presidents_dups = [l[l.find('president/')+len('president/'):] for l in every_link if 'president' in l]
presidents_dups = [l[0:l.find('/')] for l in presidents_dups]
set2 = set()
presidents = []
for l in presidents_dups:
    if l not in set2:
        presidents.append(l)
        seen.add(l)

presidents = sorted(presidents)

# the following two lines - now commented out - were used to identify duplicates in the original every_link array
# import collections
# print [l for l, count in collections.Counter(every_link).items() if count > 1]

# define a function to clean & store speeches from 'every_link' repository

def processURL(l):
        open_url = urllib2.urlopen(l).read()
        item_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_url)
        item_div = item_soup.find('div',{'id':'transcript'},{'class':'displaytext'})
        item_str = item_div.text.lower()
        item_str_processed = punctuation.sub('',item_str)
        item_str_processed_final = item_str_processed.replace('—',' ')

        splitlink = l.split("/")
        president = splitlink[4]
        speech_num = splitlink[-1].split("-")[1]
        filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president, speech_num)

        return filename, item_str_processed_final # returning a tuple

# right now, this loop only works for 423 speeches - where are the remaining ones?
for l in every_link:
    filename, content = processURL(l) # tuple unpacking
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: Are you certain `every_link` contains the number of elements you are expecting before the loop is ran?

Comment: Yes. `print(len(every_link)` yields 911 links contained; `print(len(set(every_link)))` also yields 911, showing that there are 911 distinct speeches in `every_link`.

Comment: I believe you are checking the number of iterations by the file produced (wild guess). Did you check that you aren't overwriting the files? The loop could execute 911 times and yet overwrite about half of them and thus result in only 423 file in the output.

Comment: If I were overwriting the files, wouldn't the loop stop at half (455) and not 423? How could I check that I am overwriting the files?

Comment: I suggest inserting print statements to track the operation of processURL.  For starters, print the return value to ensure that you're getting only 423 total returns (not dropping them in the post-processing).  Then back up to the seminal comparison -- unroll the comprehension, if necessary, to check the name and the link.

Comment: Besides, there's an error in how you are building the `presidents`. You are using `if l not in set2` but then you add in `seen` instead of `set2` so `presidents` contains duplicates.  I'd suggest to simpy avoid the explicit loops to remove duplicates. Use `list(set(presidents_dups))` or `sorted(set(president_dups))`.

Comment: `presidents` isn't really relevant to the `for` loop, though. I was simply verifying that I had all 43 presidents' speeches accounted for in `every_link`

Comment: I just ran `print l` along with another run of that `for` loop. It stopped at 423, again. Towards the end, the `processURL()` was alternating processing `fdroosevelt` and `harding`.